# Does my router needs to support VLAN tagging for this setup?

Tags: networking, virtualization, routing, vlan, bridge

I am trying to virtualize my home server.
I want to create multiple VMs for different purposes (1 VM for nf4 share server, 1 VM for owncloud, etc.). I need to be able to access this services (in the VMs) from outside world ofc. I am using qemu/kvm for creating VMs (linux host, linux and windows guests).
This is what I do: On the host I create a tap interface and a bridge. Then I remove the IPs from the tap interface and my physical interface (eth0). Then I add eth0 and tap0 interfaces to my bridge (br0). Then I add IP to my bridge (the same IP I removed from eth0) and change the default gateway on the bridge to what it was on eth0.

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
modprobe tun
ip tuntap add dev tap0 mode tap user ivailo
ip link add name br0 type bridge stp_state 0
ip link set br0 up
ip link set enp5s1 down
ip link set enp5s1 up promisc on
ip link set tap0 up promisc on
ip addr del 192.168.0.102/24 dev enp5s1
ip link set enp5s1 master br0
ip link set tap0 master br0
ip addr add 192.168.0.102/24 brd + dev br0
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev br0
```

After this my internet works. **BUT** when i start my qemu VM with

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -drive file=/usr/share/ovmf/ovmf_code_x64.bin,format=raw,readonly=on,if=pflash -enable-kvm -machine q35 -cpu host -smp cores=4,threads=1,maxcpus=4 -m 4048 -net nic,macaddr=02:68:b3:29:da:98 -net tap,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no -drive file=~/debian.iso,index=0,media=cdrom
```

I don't have internet access from my VM (I can't ping google.bg, the host or any pc on the LAN, "network is unreachable").
I tried doing the same thing inside VMWare:

> created 2 VMs with NAT network (they can talk between each other,
>   access my LAN and Internet, but no device on my LAN except the host
>   can access them (as it should be)). Then in first VM did the same
>   thing i did before on the host (created tap,bridge, added eth0 and
>   tap0 to br0 and started the qemu VM(with same command))

and the qemu VM inside first vmware vm was able to access internet and i was able to access/ping it from the second vm. This means I did set up everything correctly before.

**So I came to the conclusion that my router is the problem. So I am going to buy a new one. But does the router need to support VLAN tagging to do this (to bridge my VM's tap device to my physical device and forward ports to the VM)**

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand the reason for your question about you needing a router with vlan support.
I can't see that you're currently using vlans right now. So what makes you think you would need a router with vlan support?

Comment: I don't think I am dealing with VLANs but I was not entirely sure because I don't really know that much about networking. I was not entirely sure if that tap0 is just another interface like eth0 for example (which as far as I understand it is) or if it creates some kind of VLAN (which doesn't make sense but ...).